# Using GPG Encryption with Powershell in a scheduled task

Tags: powershell, networking, encryption, gnupg, windows-task-scheduler

I just spent a fair bit of time trying to figure out why I couldn't get GPG Encryption to work in a powershell script called from a scheduled task on one of our servers.  I downloaded Gpg4WIN which is a free encryption tool, although they do take donations, and installed it on a Windows 2008 R2 Server.  Installation is fairly straight-forward although the Kleopatra interface can be a little glitchy but there are plenty of places out there where you can get information on installing with via a cmd line.  Once it was installed I setup a task and the first problem that came up was that it wouldn't recognize the public key of one of our clients so I'd have to select the option that I really, really, really, trusted the provider of the key which is fine but it can't be scheduled.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what the problem was so I thought I would throw it out here in case someone else runs into the same problem.  After I installed Gpg4WIN I was not prompted to reboot so I didn't.  Didn't want to take the server off line if I didn't have to. That's all it took. Once I rebooted it took one line in a .ps1 file that excepts wild cards.

gpg --encrypt --recipient "Jon Doe" \10.8.0.000\NetworkDirectory/DirectoryOntheMachine (D:)*.*

Where Jon Doe is the name that came with the public key I imported into Kleopatra.